# struts2 jsp dynamic request attributes

Tags: jsp, struts2, attributes, request

I'm wondering how to get a dynamic request attribute. I'll try to explain:

My action make a List of some dynamic fields from database for a form.
This List is iterated by the following code in the jsp file:

```
<s:iterator value="category.categoryFields">
 <s:textfield name="%{name}" label="%{name}" value="" />
</s:iterator>
```

With this, all the needed fields are displayed on the page.

What i want now, is the request attribute wich is named the same name as the value of %{name} in the value of the textfield.
I thought it was this:

```
<s:iterator value="category.categoryFields">
 <s:textfield name="%{name}" label="%{name}" value="%{#request.name}" />
</s:iterator>
```

But that doesn't work.

I don't know how to put the %{name} variable in the place of the .name.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: i am not sure about your question, can you show the action class code? moreover tell us where you are setting those `name` attributes in your action class which you want to fetch from the request?

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, but I found the solution to my problem already today. Took me a while, but what I needed to do was: value="%{#request[name]}" instead of value="%{#request.name}"

Answer (score 1):

Needed to use

```
 <s:textfield name="%{name}" label="%{name}" value="%{#request[name]}" />
```

instead of

```
 <s:textfield name="%{name}" label="%{name}" value="%{#request.name}" />
```